# Design a transfer pattern in inventory management

Tags: java, flutter, uml

I'm designing a Class Diagram for an Inventory management software. Basically it has 3 concepts: **Item**, **Box** and a class association **Distribution** as below.

[image]

An Item can be placed in many box with different quantity. A Box can have many Items, of course, with different quantity. And the relationship between them only forms when a box does have an item with a quantity recorded as *distributedQuantity* in Distribution class.

And now I'm struggling for designing a class to record transfer's item from one box to another. Let's call it **Transfer** concept which includes the executed date and transferred quantity.

Some cases can happen when transferring a particular item from the first box to the second box:

- In the first box: If the transferred quantity is equal to the quantity in the box, the link between them is delete. Otherwise, only the distributed quantity in the Distribution class is modified.
- In the second box: If there is already a link between this item and the box (which means this box already has this item), the distributed quantity will be modified. Else, a new link forms.

Initially, I tried to link Transfer to Distribution because this concept contents both data of Item and Box. But it only works in case the first and the second box both has the item transferred.

I don't know if there is a standard (transaction) pattern for this.

Comment: Where in that model is the `Inventory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instances of `Transfer` are used to record the *history* of what happened with instances of `Distribution`. There are two approaches to model this.

**1. Copy all information in Transfer**

Do not associate Transfer with anything that can be deleted, because if it is deleted, you loose information. I suppose that instances of Item, Box and Distribution can all be deleted. Copy all information in the attributes of Transfer. This means that Transfer has all information about the item, the first box, the second box and the transferredQuantity stored in its attributes. Class Transfer does not have any associations.

**2. Do not delete objects, but mark them as dead**

In this approach, you don't delete any objects, you just mark them as dead when they are not supposed to live anymore. You can do this by adding a boolean attribute 'dead' (or 'deleted'). Now, you can associate Transfer with Item and 2 Boxes. Let Transfer have attribute 'transferredQuantity'. The drawback of this approach is that when you need to extend the model with extra classes and associations, you constantly need to realize that you have dead objects in your model, which may influence the multiplicities.

Comment: I guess I'll go with the second approach because what I forgot to mention is Item is already not deleted during time. Thank for suggesting the relationship of Transfer with 1 Item and 2 Boxes. It could work in my case.